# Previewing Image on Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I was just wondering if I can display image that I choose on my files and easily preview it on my form, I was using contact form 7 on Wordpress and I need your help

For example: I'm picking an image on my device and a soon as I picked it, the image will be displayed on the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code snippet to preview uploaded image on contact form 7

This `input[name=image]` must match your input type file name

In your contact form 7 create one empty div with the id as  `divid` i.e. `<div id='divid'></div>`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('input[name=image]').on('change', function(){
        alert('fd');
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                jQuery('#divid').html('<img src="'+e.target.result+'">');
            }
            console.log(this.files[0]);
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can I just put this jquery inside the form??

Comment: I prefer to put this in footer.php file or any js file which is loading on a page where contact form is placed

Comment: You can give a try buy putting this script in a form itself. Just wrap code in `<script></script>` tag

Comment: Along with the other comment... You should minify the script, as CF7 will add the AUTO-P if you leave it as it appears above.  Minify it, and place between `<script>/*minified-script*/</script>` then you can put it in the form.

Comment: @MominIqbal the image still wont show already check my form 
`<label> [file* file-507 limit:10485760 filetypes:png|jpeg id:image class:imageClass]</label>
<div id="divid">
</div>`

Comment: name of your file input is `file-507` so you need to update the jquery code `jQuery('input[name=file-507]').on('change', function(){`

Comment: already change it, but still no changes. may be you cant put script on the form editor itself?

Comment: try to debug script, by using console or alert message. Whether it is working or not on your website

Comment: @MominIqbal also I used console and found this error `DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content`