# Preview upload image using contact form7 plugin

Tags: javascript, forms, image, contact-form-7

In my contact form7, I upload an image.
I need to preview this image before submit.
Can you help me?
Best regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Previewing Image on Contact Form 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66275673/previewing-image-on-contact-form-7) Also see: [CF7 file upload image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48857451/cf7-file-upload-image)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Erik, I found the solution.
In case other users have the same issue, I share here the code:

```
[file fileuploader filetypes:jpg id:uploader]
<img id="preview" src="#" />
<script>
var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
uploader.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  var binaryData = [];
  binaryData.push(document.getElementById('uploader').files);
  if (binaryData) preview.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(binaryData[0][0]);
});
</script>
```